# Performing a function one time and print its result multiple times instead of performing it again for each print

Tags: php, xml, function, loops, foreach

I am getting the node list from a large XML, and then unique the list to remove duplicates, now I want to print the list into multiple select input form, however, it takes a moment for each select input to print as the function seems to repeat itself.

Is it possible to do the function one time, and save the results and print them multiple times?

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("URL Read Error");

// Get unique list of nodes in XML
function getNodes($xml) {

    // Create an empty array
    $nodes = array();

        array_push($nodes, $xml->getName());

            foreach ($xml->children() as $node) {

                $nodes = array_merge($nodes, getNodes($node));

            }

  return array_unique($nodes);

}

function nodesList() {

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("URL Read Error");
    $nodes = getNodes($xml); 
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {

        echo "<option value=" . $node . ">" . $node . "</option>";

    }
}

<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
<?php echo nodesList(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call `getNodes` once, you can do this outside the `nodesList` method and pass the list of nodes returned into this function instead.

I've changed the name of `nodesList` to `echoNodes` as it reflects the actual code better (IMHO)...

```
function echoNodes($nodes) {
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo "<option value=" . $node . ">" . $node . "</option>";
    }
}

$url = $_POST['url'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("URL Read Error");
$nodes = getNodes($xml);

// Display nodes
echoNodes($nodes);
```